Azure portal: Single ARM template for Function App deployment with custom domain fails with "certificates/mycertificate ... not found"
Hello fellow engineers!
I am trying to understand a bit how to use ARM templates to automate deployment of Function App with my custom domain. Leaving the initial setup (Storage account, App Service plan, Log Analytics, Key Vault(with "mycertificate"), Application Insigths) of the resource group aside I want to focus here just on the deployment of Function App.
In my ARM template I have following resources:

"type": "Microsoft.Web/sites" - Function App itself
"type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/extensions" - Zip deployment
"type": "Microsoft.Web/certificates" - certificate deployment to App Service
"type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/hostNameBindings" - certificate reference from Function App

The resources have "dependsOn" set up in a chain like 4(last) < 3 < 2 < 1(first).
Now if I run ARM template with resources 1,2,3,4 it does not work. It gives me

"The Resource 'Microsoft.Web/certificates/mycertificate' under
resource group 'ResourceGroupName' was not found."

But if I run ARM template with resources 1,2,3 it does succeed and then I can run again ARM template with resources 1,2,3,4 and then this one also succeeds => I have successfully deployed Function App with certificate.
While I am quite happy to know there is some path to achieve what I am planning to do, I must say the necessity to run two deployments (with resources 1,2,3 and then 1,2,3,4) is quite cumbersome.
I hope someone can explain why this works as it works, and maybe has some suggestion how to do it without the intermediate step of deployment of 1,2,3.
For reference, here are resources 3 and 4:
{
    "type":"Microsoft.Web/certificates",
    "name":"mycertificate",
    "apiVersion":"2016-03-01",
    "location":"[resourceGroup().location]",
    "dependsOn":[...],
    "properties":{
        "keyVaultId":"[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', variables('keyVaultName'))]",
        "keyVaultSecretName":"mycertificate",
        "serverFarmId":"[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('appServicePlanName'))]"
    }
},
{
    "type":"Microsoft.Web/sites/hostNameBindings",
    "apiVersion":"2023-01-01",
    "name":"myfunction/myfunction.mydomain.com",
    "location":"[resourceGroup().location]",
    "dependsOn":[
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/certificates', 'mycertificate')]"
    ],
    "properties":{
        "siteName":"myfunction",
        "hostNameType":"Verified",
        "sslState":"SniEnabled",
        "thumbprint":"[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/certificates', 'mycertificate'), '2019-08-01').Thumbprint]",
        "customHostNameDnsRecordType":"CName"
    }
}

Thanks for any help.

I think the issue you're encountering is due to the timing of resource creation and dependencies within the ARM template deployment process.
In the first Deployment (Resources 1, 2, 3):
Resources 1, 2, and 3 are deployed. The Function App is created, the zip deployment is done, and the certificate is deployed to the App Service.
In the second Deployment (Resources 1, 2, 3, 4):
Resources 1, 2, and 3 are already deployed, so Azure can reference them. Resource 4 (hostNameBindings) depends on the certificate (resource 3). During the second deployment, Azure sees that resource 3 (certificate) already exists from the first deployment, so it is able to bind the hostname to the Function App.
Try deploying your function first:
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
  "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
  "name": "functionAppDeployment",
  "properties": {
    "mode": "Incremental",
    "template": {
      "resources": [
        {
          "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
          "name": "functionApp",
          "apiVersion": "2021-02-01",
          "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "properties": {
            "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('appServicePlanName'))]"
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/extensions",
          "name": "functionAppDeploy",
          "apiVersion": "2021-02-01",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', 'functionApp')]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "appName": "functionApp",
            "slotName": "production",
            "version": "1.0",
            "type": "zip",
            "content": "<zip package content>"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

And then do something like this:
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
  "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
  "name": "certAndHostNameBindingDeployment",
  "dependsOn": [
    "functionAppDeployment"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "mode": "Incremental",
    "template": {
      "resources": [
        {
          "type": "Microsoft.Web/certificates",
          "name": "mycertificate",
          "apiVersion": "2021-02-01",
          "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "dependsOn": [
            "functionAppDeployment"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "keyVaultId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', variables('keyVaultName'))]",
            "keyVaultSecretName": "mycertificate",
            "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('appServicePlanName'))]"
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/hostNameBindings",
          "name": "myfunction/myfunction.mydomain.com",
          "apiVersion": "2023-01-01",
          "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "dependsOn": [
            "mycertificate"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "siteName": "functionApp",
            "hostNameType": "Verified",
            "sslState": "SniEnabled",
            "thumbprint": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/certificates', 'mycertificate'), '2021-02-01').thumbprint]",
            "customHostNameDnsRecordType": "CName"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}


Thanks @TempoClick for reply. I think you are right that this is a timing issue. I have tried the trick with "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments" but it does not help. Logically I would think that setting up "dependsOn" as you suggested would help but no...
